# C Gameboard with a 2d Array Issues

Tags: c, arrays, init

UPDATE:
fixed hanging pointer which solved a lot of my issues. Also reversed my Game_board init. I then created a move method which test pieces.

Suggestions: Careful with hanging pointers and memory allocation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question. (Links to your code are not a substitute - they could be dead tomorrow) No dings this time, just fix it.

Comment: I edited for you. Always indent code by 4-space so it formats as code (fixed width text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use of an Uninitialized Pointer**

A big problem is you use `char *tempLabel;` as an *uninitialized pointer*. (Where does it point? What valid memory address does it hold as its value?) Attempting to copy data to it is guaranteed to SegFault. Instead, you need to validate the length of `game_piece_get_label(piece)` and **allocate** `length + 1` characters of storage with `malloc, calloc or realloc`, e.g..

For example:

```
char *game_piece_to_string (struct game_piece *piece)
{
    char *tempLabel;    /* uninitialized pointer */
    size_t len = strlen (game_piece_get_label(piece));

    tempLabel = malloc (len + 1);
    if (tempLabel == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-tempLabel");
        return NULL;
    }
    memcpy (tempLabel, game_piece_get_label(piece), len + 1);

    if (len > 3)
        tempLabel[1] = '\0';
    for (size_t i = 3; i > len; i--)
        strcat(tempLabel, " ");

    return tempLabel;
}
```

Note, what you are trying to do with your conditionals and a loop with `sizeof (a_pointer)` makes little sense. Presumable you want the *length* of `tempLabel`.

**Problems Allocating the Board**

Your allocation of *pointer-to-pointer-to* `struct game_piece` is almost backwards. You must allocate `row` number of pointers first, then allocate `col` number of `struct game_piece` per-row. You will then have storage allocated at each `[i][j]` for one `struct game_piece` -- which is where you decision to put `char label[30];` as a single-member within a struct unnecessarily complicates referencing the `label`.

Making the changes, you could do something like:

```
void game_board_init(struct game_board* game_board, int rows, int cols)
{
    /* allocate row number of pointers */
    game_board->board = malloc (sizeof(*game_board->board)*rows);
    /* allocate col number of **game_board->board per row
     * (e.g. col * sizeof (struct game_piece) per row)
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        game_board->board[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct game_piece) * cols);
    }
    game_board->row = rows;
    game_board->col = cols;
    for (int i=0; i < rows; i++){
        printf("\n");
        for (int j=0; j < cols; j++) {
            game_piece_init_default(&game_board->board[i][j]);
            printf("%s ",game_board->board[i][j].label);
        }
    }
}
```

All of this points to the fact you are either (1) compiling your code with without *warnings enabled*, or (2) consciously ignoring the warnings your compiler is generating. For gcc/clang add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (at minimum) to your compiler options, for VS add `/W3` and do not accept code until it compiles *without warning*. Let your compiler help you write better code. (this will save you an incredible amount of time in the long run)

You will also want to look at [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and talk to the duck... Really, it helps `:)`

Enable compiler warnings, take a look at the debugging link, and then edit and **add** to the bottom of your question any other specific areas where you are stuck and I'm happy to help further.

Making the above changes, and adding the following "stub" to silence warnings for unused variables in your unfinished `game_board_move_piece`, e.g.

```
    if (game_board || src_row || src_col || dest_row || dest_col) {}
```

I can compile your code with gcc using:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -Ofast -o gb_init gb_init.c
```

*without warning*. You have a bit of additional debugging to do as evidenced below:

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/game_board_init
Please enter the number of rows.
3
Please enter the number of columns.
3

--- --- ---
--- --- ---
--- --- --- Please enter a label for a new piece. Enter "Q" when done.
a
Please enter a row for the piece.
1
Please enter a column for the piece.
1
New piece "a" added.
Please enter a label for a new piece. Enter "Q" when done.c
Please enter a row for the piece.
2
Please enter a column for the piece.
2
New piece "c" added.
Please enter a label for a new piece. Enter "Q" when done.b
Please enter a row for the piece.
0
Please enter a column for the piece.
0
New piece "b" added.
Please enter a label for a new piece. Enter "Q" when done.q
try again -kelly
b  ------
---a  ---
------c  Would you like to move a piece? Enter "Y" to move a piece.
Y
Please enter the piece's row.2
Please enter the piece's column.2
Please enter the piece's new row.2
Please enter the piece's new column.0
A piece is already in that space.
try again -kelly
b  ------
---a  ---
------c  Would you like to move a piece? Enter "Y" to move a piece.
n
```

That's where the conversation with the "duck" comes into play...

**Complete Test Code Used**

The following is what I used to compile without warning and generate the output above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXL 30     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

struct game_piece
{
    char label[MAXL];
};

struct game_board
{
    struct game_piece **board;
    int row, col;
};

void game_piece_init_default(struct game_piece* piece)
{
    strcpy(piece->label, "---");
}

void game_piece_init(struct game_piece* piece, char* new_label)
{
    size_t len = strlen (new_label);

    if (len < MAXL)
        memcpy (piece->label, new_label, len + 1);
    else {
        fputs ("warning: label truncated.\n", stderr);
        memcpy (piece->label, new_label, MAXL-1);
        piece->label[MAXL-1] = 0;   /* nul-terminate */
    }
}

char *game_piece_get_label (struct game_piece *piece)
{
    return piece->label;
}

char *game_piece_to_string (struct game_piece *piece)
{
    char *tempLabel;    /* uninitialized pointer */
    size_t len = strlen (game_piece_get_label(piece));

    tempLabel = malloc (len + 1);
    if (tempLabel == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-tempLabel");
        return NULL;
    }
    memcpy (tempLabel, game_piece_get_label(piece), len + 1);

    if (len > 3)
        tempLabel[1] = '\0';
    for (size_t i = 3; i > len; i--)
        strcat(tempLabel, " ");

    return tempLabel;
}

void game_board_init(struct game_board* game_board, int rows, int cols)
{
    /* allocate row number of pointers */
    game_board->board = malloc (sizeof(*game_board->board)*rows);
    /* allocate col number of **game_board->board per row
     * (e.g. col * sizeof (struct game_piece) per row)
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        game_board->board[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct game_piece) * cols);
    }
    game_board->row = rows;
    game_board->col = cols;
    for (int i=0; i < rows; i++){
        printf("\n");
        for (int j=0; j < cols; j++) {
            game_piece_init_default(&game_board->board[i][j]);
            printf("%s ",game_board->board[i][j].label);
        }
    }
}

int game_board_is_space_valid(struct game_board* game_board, 
                                int row, int col)
{
    if (row > game_board->row || col > game_board->col)
        return 0;
    if (row < 0 || col < 0) 
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

int game_board_add_piece(struct game_board* game_board, 
                        struct game_piece* piece, int row, int col)
{
    if (game_board_is_space_valid(game_board, row, col) == 0) 
        return 0;
    if (strncmp(game_board->board[row][col].label, "---", 3) == 0) {
        game_board->board[row][col] = *piece;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int game_board_move_piece(struct game_board* game_board, 
                    int src_row, int src_col, int dest_row, int dest_col)
{
    return 0;
    if (game_board || src_row || src_col || dest_row || dest_col) {}
}

void game_board_print(struct game_board* game_board)
{
    int col = 3;
    int row = 3;
    printf("try again -kelly");
    for (int i=0; i < row; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j=0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("%s",game_piece_to_string(&game_board->board[i][j]));
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    /* declare local variables */
    int row;
    int col;
    int destRow;
    int destCol;
    int rowNum;
    int colNum;
    struct game_board board;
    struct game_piece piece;
    char input_string[30];

    /* get the size of the game board */
    printf("Please enter the number of rows.\n");
    scanf("%d", &rowNum);

    printf("Please enter the number of columns.\n");
    scanf("%d", &colNum);

    game_board_init(&board, rowNum, colNum);

    /* get the first piece's label */
    printf("Please enter a label for a new piece. "
            "Enter \"Q\" when done.\n");
    scanf("%s", input_string);

    while (strcmp(input_string, "Q") != 0 && strcmp(input_string, "q") != 0)
    {
        game_piece_init(&piece, input_string);

        /* get the location to place the piece */
        printf("Please enter a row for the piece.\n");
        scanf("%d", &row);

        printf("Please enter a column for the piece.\n");
        scanf("%d", &col);

        /* verify the space is valid then add the piece to the board */
        if (game_board_is_space_valid(&board, row, col))
        {
            if (game_board_add_piece(&board, &piece, row, col))
            {
                printf("New piece \"%s\" added.\n", 
                        game_piece_get_label(&piece));
            }
            else
            {
                printf("A piece is already at that space.\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid row and/or column.\n");
        }

        /* get the label for the next piece */
        printf("Please enter a label for a new piece. "
                "Enter \"Q\" when done.");
        scanf("%s", input_string);
    }

    /* print the board and check if user wants to move a piece */
    game_board_print(&board);
    printf("Would you like to move a piece? Enter \"Y\" to move a piece.\n");
    scanf("%s", input_string);

    while (strcmp(input_string, "Y") == 0 || strcmp(input_string, "y") == 0)
    {
        /* get the location of the piece */
        printf("Please enter the piece's row.");
        scanf("%d", &row);

        printf("Please enter the piece's column.");
        scanf("%d", &col);

        /* get the destination for the piece */
        printf("Please enter the piece's new row.");
        scanf("%d", &destRow);

        printf("Please enter the piece's new column.");
        scanf("%d", &destCol);

        /* verify both spaces are valid then move the piece */
        if (game_board_is_space_valid(&board, row, col) &&
            game_board_is_space_valid(&board, destRow, destCol))
        {
            if (game_board_move_piece(&board, row, col, destRow, destCol))
            {
                printf("Piece moved to new space.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("A piece is already in that space.\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("A row or column is invalid. No piece moved.\n");
        }

        /* print the board and check if the user wants move another piece */
        game_board_print(&board);
        printf("Would you like to move a piece? "
                "Enter \"Y\" to move a piece.\n");
        scanf("%s", input_string);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First off, thanks for the feedback!, Secondly. I have been compiling within Netbeans, but it stopped compiling? or providing errors? I'm not sure what happened. So I switched to an online compiler and that has kind of been giving issues as well, my code will begin to run by never stop and exceed runtime.

Comment: I think I figured out your Secondly `:)` If you are on windows, you can download either MinGW or MS Developer Toolkit and get either `gcc` or the older VS compiler in a relatively small install (I would use MinGW to get gcc). You can also download VS Community 2017 -- but that is about 8G.

Comment: I've updated my to_string method; 

char* game_piece_to_string(struct game_piece* piece)

{

    char* temp = malloc(4 * (sizeof(char)));

    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        *(temp+i) = piece->label[i];
    }

    temp[3] = '\0';

    return temp;
}

Comment: What Operating System do you have?

Comment: I downloaded VS but I have Mac. I couldn't find anyway to run C programs on VS on mac.

Comment: Simple. I presume `cl` is still the name of the VS compiler there. Make sure it is in your path, and you should be able to do `cl /nologo /W3 /Tc yoursource.c`. I always create an `obj` and `bin` directory below the current to keep the source directory clean. Then you can add `cl /nologo /W3 /Foobj/ /Febin/nameforexe /Tc yoursource.c` to put the .obj and exe files in the `obj` and `bin` directories. The Mac may have changed the `/` option indicator to `-` or `--` you will just have to check.

Comment: Just use `temp[i]` instead of `*(temp+i)` in your `to_string` *function* -- it's easier to read for many people (they are identical in what they reference). And you can surround your code in `backticks`, e,g, `\`code\`` in these comments to make it format as fixed-text.

Comment: Also I don't see a `game_board_free` function yet to `free` the `rows` and `pointers` you allocate. You will `free` in the reverse order you allocate. (e.g. `for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows; i++) free (game_board->board[i]);` then `free (game_board->board);` to free the pointers.

Comment: If I wasn't clear, compiling with VS, forget about the VS code IDE (you can edit with it if you like), but always compile from the command line. So open the terminal, make sure `cl` is in your path (just type `cl /?` to spit out the help to check) and then change to your source directory, (do a `mkdir obj bin` to create the extra dirs) and then enter `cl /nologo /W3 /Foobj/ /Febin/nameforexe /Tc yoursource.c` to invoke the compiler and compile `yoursource.c` into `bin/nameofexe` as your executable. Then `./bin/nameofexe` to run it.

Comment: I will have access to a compiler in an hour or so. For now I am stuck with the online compiler, which isn't telling me where my whole in the code is that is causing it not to compile. I think I have something causing runtime to exceed and I'm not sure where.

Comment: Check if VS installed a `VS Developers Command Prompt` -- which will already set a terminal with the proper build environment and PATH for you.

Comment: I appreciate all of the help! Using your code I still was not able to use any of these online compilers. I think I just have to wait until I get home and use command line.

Comment: Yep, I compiled on an old VS2010 compiler (you have to remove all the C99 `for` loops (e.g. just declare `size_t i;` and remove the `size_t` from `for (size_t i = 0;...`)) Also, add `/wd4996` to disable the one warning that VS wants you to include a `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to not complain about using `scanf` instead of `scanf_s` -- MS psycho-babble... If you have VS 2017 -- you won't have to change a thing. I keep a VM on the LAN that has Win7 just to test with VS. Ancient but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In general we MUCH prefer that you paste your code here, rather than link to it. (The link is likely to go stale over time). You should also describe what error message you see, in order to make sure we're all on the same page.

You may have multiple problems, but the first surely is the fact that in game_piece_to_label you are using an uninitialized pointer.

```
char* game_piece_to_string(struct game_piece* piece)
{
    char* tempLabel;
    strcpy(tempLabel, game_piece_get_label(piece));
```

You need to malloc some memory and assign it to tempLabel.  As it stands, you're writing to random memory, which for me results in a segfault.